# Why does not alert() function work in Tauri app?

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

When I use the `alert()` function in a tauri app. Nothing happens to the app, I don't get an alert box or anything.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";


function Football() {
    const shoot = () => {
      alert("Great Shot!");
    }
  
    return (
      <button onClick={shoot}>Take the shot!</button>
    );
  }
  
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Football />);
```

When I open the same `.js` file in my browser I get an alert message. What exactly is happening that it doesnt show the alert message in the tauri app.

Comment: maybe because it rewrote the alert function like ``alert = (msg)=>{console.log(`rewrote as console.log(${msg})`)}``? Maybe try to log on console its function body: `console.log(alert.toString()) `

Comment: Is there any javascript error in the page?

Comment: Is the app running in a sandboxed iframe that doesn't allow modals?

Comment: @JoanLara no when I start the same app in my browser using ```npm start``` I get an error notification when I click the button but nothing happens in my app when I click the button

Comment: Check that the "tauri": { "allowlist": { "dialog": { "message": true } } } is set to true in tauri.conf.json